# c code make successfully in Mac while failed in Linux

Tags: linux, macos, makefile, exit

I have some source files(e.g, layout.cpp). I can use 'make' command in my local MAC machine. After make successfully, I copied all files to remote Linux machine. However, the executable file in my MAC machine could not be executed in remote Linux machine. The error message is below.

> > layout is not a binary executable file

I think the failure is due to format of layout file is 'Mach-O 64-bit executable', which couldn't run in linux machine.

Therefore, I tried to make source files in remote linux machine. However, it showed a lot of error messages like below.

> > layout.cpp:75: error: ‘exit’ was not declared in this scope
> >
> > layout.cpp:88: error: ‘strcpy’ was not declared in this scope

But these errors didn't show in make process in MAC. Are these errors caused by difference of compilers in MAC and Linux? Since there are so many different errors, hence we could not simply add '#include cstdlib' or '#include string.h' to solve that. Thanks.

Source Code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <deque>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

// layout routines and constants
#include <layout.h>
#include <parse.h>
#include <graph.h>

// MPI
#ifdef MUSE_MPI
    #include <mpi.h>
#endif

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    // initialize MPI
    int myid, num_procs;

 #ifdef MUSE_MPI
     MPI_Init ( &argc, &argv );
     MPI_Comm_size ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &num_procs );
     MPI_Comm_rank ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, &myid );
 #else
    myid = 0;
    num_procs = 1;
 #endif

  // parameters that must be broadcast to all processors
 int rand_seed;
 float edge_cut;

 char int_file[MAX_FILE_NAME];
 char coord_file[MAX_FILE_NAME];
 char real_file[MAX_FILE_NAME];
 char parms_file[MAX_FILE_NAME];

 int int_out = 0;
 int edges_out = 0;
 int parms_in = 0;
 float real_in = -1.0;

 // user interaction is handled by processor 0
 if ( myid == 0 )
 {
     if ( num_procs > MAX_PROCS )
     {
    cout << "Error: Maximum number of processors is " << MAX_PROCS << "." << endl;
    cout << "Adjust compile time parameter." << endl;
    #ifdef MUSE_MPI
      MPI_Abort ( MPI_COMM_WORLD, 1 );
    #else
      exit (1);
    #endif
}

// get user input
    parse command_line ( argc, argv );
rand_seed = command_line.rand_seed;
edge_cut = command_line.edge_cut;
int_out = command_line.int_out;
edges_out = command_line.edges_out;
parms_in = command_line.parms_in;
real_in = command_line.real_in;
strcpy ( coord_file, command_line.coord_file.c_str() );
strcpy ( int_file, command_line.sim_file.c_str() );
strcpy ( real_file, command_line.real_file.c_str() );
strcpy ( parms_file, command_line.parms_file.c_str() );

 }

 // now we initialize all processors by reading .int file
  #ifdef MUSE_MPI
     MPI_Bcast ( &int_file, MAX_FILE_NAME, MPI_CHAR, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD );
  #endif
  graph neighbors ( myid, num_procs, int_file );


  // finally we output file and quit
  float tot_energy;
  tot_energy = neighbors.get_tot_energy ();
  if ( myid == 0 )
  {
   neighbors.write_coord ( coord_file );
   cout << "Total Energy: " << tot_energy << "." << endl
        << "Program terminated successfully." << endl;
  }

  // MPI finalize
 #ifdef MUSE_MPI
    MPI_Finalize ();
 #endif

}
```

Comment: If you want help you should show some source code...

Comment: If you're code is so sloppy that you don't have `exit` and `strcpy` declared, you need to get the code compiling sanely on Mac OS X before you go porting it.  Sanely means `gcc -Wall` at bare minimum; I routinely use `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` (I use these on Mac OS X 10.9.1 with GCC 4.8.2).  When your code compiles cleanly on Mac OS X with those options, then think about porting elsewhere.  And `<cstdlib>` is not appropriate unless you're really working in C++, but then you should not be using `strcpy()` at all!

Comment: Note that one 'feature' of C++ standard headers is that they can include each other. It is possible that on Mac OS X there is a header that you include which in turn includes `<cstdlib>` and `<cstring>`, but the same header on Linux does not — so you have to fix your code accordingly.  If you use a function from a header, include that header; do not rely on some other header to include it for you.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I have added source code. I found the compiler has been defined in my setting file. It's 'g++ 03'. I am confused about this error. thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing several standard `#include` notably the standard C++ header [`<cstdlib>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstdlib) or the C header `<stdlib.h>` (for `exit`) and the standard C++ header [`<cstring>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/cstring) or the C header `<string.h>` (for `strcpy`), as commented by [Jonathan Leffler](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15168/jonathan-leffler) (who also explained why that works on MacOSX but not on Linux).

You probably should switch to [C++11](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11) standard. This means installing a recent GCC (4.8) and compile with `g++ -std=c++11` and of course `-Wall -g` (to get all warnings and debugging information) ....

And you did not search enough on these issues. You could have typed `man exit` to get  [exit(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/exit.3.html) man page, or `man strcpy` to get [strcpy(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strcpy.3.html) man page. Both man pages give relevant C include headers....

BTW, the bug is really in your source code. A code using `exit` really should include `<stdlib.h>` or `<cstdlib>` explicitly by itself (at least for readability reasons). You should not suppose that some other system header is (accidentally) including that.